# While integrating sin and cos using sympy the output must be same, but integration of cos gives a value of order -16

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-integration

While integrating sin and cos using sympy the output must be same, but integration of cos gives a value of order -16 which is essentially 0 upon rounding. Any reason why it gives such a low value for cos and a direct 0 for sin?

```
i/p: f=(sp.integrate(sp.cos(x),(x,-np.pi,np.pi)))
o/p: 2.44929359829471e-16


i/p: f=(sp.integrate(sp.sin(x),(x,-np.pi,np.pi)))
o/p: 0
```

Comment: Be very carefull not to use pi from math or numpy as they are floating point. You need sympy's pi to get exact results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point numbers (basically decimal numbers) have limited precision which leads to some strange things from time to time.

For example `0.1 + 0.2` will give `0.30000000000000004`

In your example, the e-16 is very small and is basically zero as you said, but somewhere in the calculation there was probably a rounding error for the cosine values but it just so happened not to be the case for the sine values. You can try a different range for the integral of sin and probably find the same thing happening.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. Though I need a more technical answer with regards to the difference between calculation of sin and cosine.

Comment: The difference has little to with any differences in the calculation of the two functions. Those functions are written by people who are well aware of the problems of floating accuracy and do what they can to mitigate them. But the difference you see is at the limit of the hardware's accuracy and so is dependent on the data, not the code.

Comment: The reason `sin` comes out as exactly 0 is probably due to the fact that the range is symmetric about the origin, and `sin(-x) == -sin(x)`, so the precision errors on one side exactly cancel out the precision errors on the other side.